# ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web Api HttpPost Action parameter can't receive axios application/json HttpPost passing data

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-3.1

I used to use Controller instead of ApiController, and today I tried to use ApiController and found below question.

ASP.NET Core Web Api HttpPost Action parameter can't receive axios `application/json` post passing data

asp.net core api code

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post(string json)
    {
        return this.Ok();
    }
}
```

frontend

```js
var json = '{"json_data":"{\"value\":\"hello world\"}';
axios.post('Test', {"json": json})
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Actual Reqeust

```
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Request Payload : 
{"json_data":"{\"value\":\"hello world\"}
```

Actual action json parameter data is `null`
Expected receive data : `{"json_data":"{\"value\":\"hello world\"}`

---

Update

I tried below code, and I get rawValue value = `{"json_data":"{\"value\":\"hello world\"}` but json value = `null`

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(string json)
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        string rawValue = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> public async Task Post(string json)

If you'd like to make HTTP quest(s) from front end with data and bind it to a ***string-type*** ACTION parameter correctly, you can try to implement and use a custom plain text input formatter.

```
public class TextPlainInputFormatter : TextInputFormatter
{
    public TextPlainInputFormatter()
    {
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add("text/plain");
        SupportedEncodings.Add(UTF8EncodingWithoutBOM);
        SupportedEncodings.Add(UTF16EncodingLittleEndian);
    }

    protected override bool CanReadType(Type type)
    {
        return type == typeof(string);
    }

    public override async Task<InputFormatterResult> ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context, Encoding encoding)
    {
        string data = null;
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(context.HttpContext.Request.Body))
        {
            data = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
        }
        return InputFormatterResult.Success(data);
    }
}
```

*Configure and add custom formatter support*

```
services.AddControllers(opt => opt.InputFormatters.Insert(0, new TextPlainInputFormatter()));
```

*Frontend code*

```
const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
};

var json = '{"json_data":"{\"value\":\"hello world\"}';

axios.post('test', json, { headers: headers })
    .then(function (response) {
        //...
```

Test Result

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Update:

[Demo Source Code Link](https://github.com/ITWeiHan-Demos/PassingJsonStringToApiDifferentWays)

I finally use `[FromBody]` and `System.Text.Json.JsonElement` to resolve the problem

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("TestUsingFromBodyAttribute")]
public object TestUsingFromBodyAttribute([FromBody] System.Text.Json.JsonElement content)
{
    return content;
}
```

Because axios default `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
it need to update `Content-Type': 'application/json`, or system'll show `415 unsupported media type`

[image]

And then it can't use `string` type or system'll show `400 bad request`

[image]

Because asp.net core check `Content-Type': 'application/json` and use `[FromBody]` will auto convert to json object (`System.Text.Json.JsonElement`), so that's why it can't use string type.
[image]

If don't want to edit axios default `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, it have to set reqeust data is object not string

[image]

Read :

- https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/sep/14/accepting-raw-request-body-content-in-aspnet-core-api-controllers

---

Early answer:

Now I use Request.Body not Action Parameter to resolve the problem, but I still don't know why it can't do it.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post()
{
    string json = null;
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        json = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    }
    //..etc
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [FromBodyAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.frombodyattribute?view=aspnetcore-5.0) for correct mapping.

Comment: Thanks, I upvote this, but I found not just this problem