# Post parameter from Angular to .Net 5 webapi are not sent

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a .Net5 Webapi with a simple controller and a HttpPost-Action:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class UploadController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("codeisvalid")]
    public bool CodeIsValid(string code)
    {
       return code == "dbddhkp";
    }
}
```

I try to call that Action from within an Angular Component:

```
this._http.post<any>(http://localhost:29438/upload/codeisvalid', { code: 'wrongcode'}).subscribe(data => {
   this.codeIsValid=data;
   this.codeChecked=true;
});
```

The action is called, but "code" is always *null*. I also tried to modify the Action to `public bool CodeIsValid([FromBody] string code)` (adding "[FromBody]") but then the method is not called anymore, but receive an error 400 instead

> "The JSON value could not be converted to System.String"

What Do I have to change to make this work?

Comment: `....post<...>(..., 'wrongcode')`. Omit the curly braces

Comment: http://localhost:29438/upload/codeisvalid?code=wrongcode

Comment: @JasonPan I did not want to use a query-Parameter for a post-Operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the answers worked for me. I finally added a little bit of Overhead to my C#-Functions. That worked without an error

```
public class CodeModel {
   public string Code {get;set;}
}

public bool CodeIsValid ([FromBody]CodeModel codemodel) {
   return codemodel.Code=="dbddhkp";
}
```

Comment: This is the correct solution.

Comment: To fix this kind of issue, as you mentioned, one solution is creating a model class based on the expected data. Another solution is implement and use a custom plain text input formatter to make data bind to a string-type action parameter correctly, can refer to this SO thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67914467/asp-net-core-3-1-web-api-httppost-action-parameter-cant-receive-axios-applicati/67965980#67965980

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all else works, instead of passing an object, just pass in `'wrongcode'`. C# is expecting *only* a string to be passed in, not a property of an object.

```
this._http.post<any>('http://localhost:29438/upload/codeisvalid', 'wrongcode').subscribe(data => {
   this.codeIsValid=data;
   this.codeChecked=true;
});
```