# ASP.NET Core MVC http post method gets null as an argument from Angular call

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core-mvc, angular15

When I pass a username as a value to the ASP.NET Core MVC action method, its parameter gets null as an argument. what can I do to avoid this?

I know it's a common question but I am stuck.

Angular code:

```
callExternalProject(username : string): Observable<any> {
      
    return this.http.post<any>(`${environment.CMRDashboardURL}/Account/LoginUser`,username) .pipe(
          catchError(error => {
              return throwError(() => new Error(error))
          })     
    );
}
```

ASP.NET Core MVC code:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult LoginUser(string  Username)
{
    string viewName = "Login";

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Username))
    {
        ViewBag.Emptybox = "User name can not be empty.";
        return View(viewName, Username);
    }
}
```

Screenshots:

Frontend screenshot

[image]

Backend screenshot

[image]

Login the third application from Angular frontend by passing the username from the Angular side

Comment: Does my answer inspire you ?

Comment: @JasonPan Thanks for your effort. I did it by changing the method get instead of post.

Answer (score 0):

**WAY 1**

I found a official doc why the issue happens.

[image]

[Custom formatters in ASP.NET Core Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/custom-formatters?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

If you want to implement this, you can [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67965980/7687666).

---

**WAY 2**

Change your code like below, you will get the value.

```
this.http
  .post<any[]>(this.apiUrl, null, {
    params: new HttpParams().set('Username', 'jason'),
  })
  .subscribe((data) => {
    this.users = data;
  });
```

---

Let me explain to you, from your code, you are using `this.http.post<any>(`${environment.CMRDashboardURL}/Account/LoginUser`,username)`, the `usename` send to backend in request body, not params.

---

#### Test Result

**Yours**

I found payload data has string.

[image]

**Mine**

[image]